# CPU or RAM better in old machine?

Tags: cpu, ram

I'm planning to use one of two old computers as a low-volume backup server. The machine will be online and files will be backed up over ssh/rsync. I will do a minimal install of Ubuntu or Debian server.

The specifications of the machines are as follows:

- Pentium3 1GHz *Coppermine* CPU with two 168-pin SDRAM DIMM slots with 320MB RAM (256MB and 64MB)
- Pentium3 450MHz *Katmai* CPU with three 168-pin SDRAM DIMM slots with 384MB RAM (256MB and two 64MB). The motherboard in this machine seems to be a little more reliable.

I only have 384MB of 168-pin SDRAM DIMMs available in total.

For the task of low-volume backup server, does it really matter which one I use? The difference in RAM is small and a previous minimal install of Ubuntu 8.04 server used <20MB RAM anyway. However, the Coppermine CPU is more than double the speed if the Katmai, so I should use that one?

Comment: I think ram is much more important than CPU specially when it comes to old computers, but the 64MB won't make much of a difference. So I'd go for the faster CPU. I assume that for some reason you cannot exchange the RAM?

Comment: @d_inevitable: I've updated my question to clarify the RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that the most important thing for a backup server is reliability, so would tend to go for that machine. You say it's `low-volume` so the CPU would be idle most of the time anyway.

Answer (score 2):

It won't matter, unless you maybe want to encrypt the backups. I don't know how Ubuntu fares as a server OS, I tend to use Debian. If it turns out you want some more services, RAM is extremely cheap and should be a good investment here.

Comment: 168-pin SDRAM DIMMs are quite hard to find :)

Answer (score 2):

I think current performance will be enough.
But think again about power consumption of such old system and reliability and noise.